# Alexa doesn't display card in the home feed

Tags: .net, alexa-skills-kit

The display card is shown on the Alexa devices with screen (1st picture) and the notification card is shown in the activity tab (2nd picture) of the companion app, but the card is not shown in the home feed (3rd picture). What could be the reason?

```
CardImage image = new CardImage {
    SmallImageUrl = "https://.../image-small.png",
    LargeImageUrl = "https://.../image-big.png"
};

response.Response.Card = new StandardCard {
    Title = Subject,
    Content = Message,
    Image = image
};

return response;
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

We need to show the card in the home feed in order to get our skill accepted as we need to make sure the user is notified of purchase.